# how do i correctly use >= and <= in code?

Tags: error-handling

I have tried many thing involving this, >=, >==, =>, ==>.i can not find one that works. hey all return either primary expression needed or expected initializer before '>'. I am creating a IR receiver latch switch and thus have to create parameters for the code because the receiver is not constant in all conditions. Full code below. Any suggestions to fix the code please reply and don't DM me. Thank you.

code:

```
int LEDState = 0;
int LEDPin = 8;
int dt = 100;
int recieverOld ==> 500 and recieverOld ==< 2000;
int recieverNew;
int recieverPin = 12;

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
Serial.begin(9600);
pinMode(LEDPin, OUTPUT);
pinMode(recieverPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
recieverNew = digitalRead(recieverPin);
if((recieverOld >== 0 && recieverOld <== 10) && (recieverNew >== 500 && recieverNew <== 2000) {
  if(LEDState == 0) {
    digitalWrite(LEDPin, HIGH);
    LEDState = 1;

  }
}
recieverOld = recieverNew;
delay(dt);
}
```

error:

expected initializer before '==' token

if one = used line 4 and related, return error expected primary-expression before '>' token

if > before = line 4 and related, return error expected initializer before '>=' token

Any solutions or suggestions welcome.

Comment: What programming language is this supposed to be?

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR**

Operators that do no exist, and that you should NOT use:

`==>`, `==<`, `>==`, `<==`

Operators that works and you can use them:

`>=` - MORE THAN OR EQUAL, compare operator, for example `X >= 5`

`<=` - LESS THAN OR EQUAL, compare operator, for example `X <= 5`

`>` - MORE THAN, compare operator, for example `X > 5`

`<` - LESS THAN, compare operator, for example `X < 5`

`==` - compare operator, when you want to compare values of the variables if they have the same value, for example `X == 5`, `Y == X`, `10 == 7`

`===` - equality operator, similar to compare operator `==`, but aditionally checks the type of a variable. for example `X === Y`, `'10' === 10`

`=` - assign operator, when you want to assign something to the variable, for example `X = 5`

`<>` OR `!=` - NOT EQUAL, compare operator, for example `X != 5`, `Y <> 10`

`!==` - similar to `!=` or `<>`, but also checks the type of a value. For example `10 !== '10'`, and will return opposite result of the equality operator `===`

Comment: if i use > or >= error still returned as initializer needed.

Comment: initialization is similar to assignment, try to use `=`

Comment: i assume this is another expression for less then? if so i also assumt the expression for more then is =+ ?

Comment: No, there is no operator `=+`, there could be an operator like `+=` which would mean something like "increment value by". For example `X = 5`, `X+= 10` - this will add `10` to `X`, so `X` will be `15`

Comment: i am trying to create a variable, so x is less then 10 and more then 0. the code i used does not allow this? What code would i have to use to make this work?

Comment: `X = 5` - you assign `5` to `X`, no `X` equals `5`, so you can check it: `X == 5`. And if you want to check that `X` is in range from `0` exclusive to `10` exclusive, you can write condition with statement: `X > 0 and X < 10`, if you want so `X` is in range from `1` to `10` inclusive, you can write: `X >= 1 and X <= 10`